# Novice needs to loop lm in R

Tags: r, loops, lm

I'm a PhD student of genetics and I am trying do association analysis of some genetic data using linear regression. In the table below I'm regressing each 'trait' against each 'SNP' There is also a interaction term include as 'var'

I've only used R for 2 weeks and I don't have any programming background so please explain any help provided as I want to understand.

This is a sample of my data:

```
Sample ID   var trait 1 trait 2 trait 3 SNP1    SNP2    SNP3
77856517    2   188      3       2        1      0       0
375689755   8   17      -1      -1        1     -1      -1
392513415   8   28       14      4        1      1       1
393612038   8   85       14      6        1      1       0
401623551   8   152      11     -1        1      0       0
348466144   7   -74      11      6        1      0       0
77852806    4   81       16      6        1      1       0
440614343   8   -93      8       0        0      1       0
77853193    5   3        6       5        1      1       1
```

and this is the code I've been using for a single regression:

```
result1 <-lm(trait1~SNP1+var+SNP1*var, na.action=na.exclude)
```

I want to run a loop where every trait is tested against each SNP.

I've been trying to modify codes I've found online but I always run into some error that I don't understand how to solve.

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: I'm worried that you have not described anything about what the "trait" numbers mean or why you want to do independent analyses on what could well be dependent predictors. A linear regression analysis presumes that change in the Y value of 10 from 17 to 27 means exactly the same as a change from 200 to 210. Is that what you wnat to know? And is it really the case that the SNP's are independent? Before accepting any answers you should be making sure that any online consultants have interviewed you adequately to offer informed advice.

Comment: I appreciate these comments. It's true that I don't understand all the data too well, but within my project it was all handled by a proper statistician. I'm not required to do an overly comprehensive analysis. The SNPs show various levels of dependence and in a perfect world I would want to learn all of this. But right now I only need to run this on a simpler level. This analysis has been done correctly already and I was told during the course of my PhD that I don't have learn it.

Comment: Trust me DWin, I know how ridiculous it is. I'm doing what I can to teach myself but it is hard to wrap my head around both statistics and coding.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I don't find the problem so easy. Specially for an R novice.

Here a solution based on creating dynamically the regression formula.
The idea is  to use `paste` function to create different formula terms, `y~ x + var + x * var` then coercing the result string tp a formula using `as.formula`. Here `y` and `x` are the formula dynamic terms: y in c(trait1,trai2,..) and x in c(SNP1,SNP2,...). Of course here I use `lapply` to loop.

```
lapply(1:3,function(i){
 y <- paste0('trait',i)
 x <- paste0('SNP',i)
 factor1 <- x
 factor2 <- 'var'
 factor3 <- paste(x,'var',sep='*')
 listfactor <- c(factor1,factor2,factor3)
 form <- as.formula(paste(y, "~",paste(listfactor,collapse="+")))
 lm(formula = form, data = dat)
})
```

I hope someone come with easier solution, ore more R-ish one:)

**EDIT**

Thanks to @DWin comment , we can simplify the formula to just `y~x*var` since it means `y` is modeled by `x`,`var` and `x*var`

So the code above will be simplified to :

```
 lapply(1:3,function(i){
     y <- paste0('trait',i)
     x <- paste0('SNP',i)
     LHS <- paste(x,'var',sep='*')
     form <- as.formula(paste(y, "~",LHS)
     lm(formula = form, data = dat)
    })
```

Comment: There is no point in going to the trouble of following the OP down the road of creating redundant code. The formula `y ~ x*var` will be quite sufficient. Look at the output of: `model.matrix(trait1~SNP1+var+SNP1*var, data.frame(trait1=188, var=2, SNP1=1) )`

Comment: @DWin thanks. the model notation that R uses is flexible and powerful but still confusing to newbie like me :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I do hope to learn a lot more of this down the line, but fore the time being I'm hoping to reverse-learn from the advice you've given. I really need to find a way to avoid running 580 single lm lines of code.