# How to use apply or lapply function

Tags: r

I have columns of data  and would like to use the WD as an independent variable and E1-E14 as dependent variable and do a regression for each and write the output to a csv file. Please help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjJgd.jpg)

This what I did, however it outputs the same results for all columns. I think the mod variable is being incorrectly set.

```
mod <- function(y) lm(E1 ~ WD , data = data)
lapply(data[,5:16], mod)
```

Comment: Please, input some example data, show us how far have you gone trying to solve your problem and what kind of output you expect.

Comment: Your `mod` function doesn't use the `y` value you pass in anywhere inside the function. You've hard coded the variable in your regression. Maybe something like this question can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733977/novice-needs-to-loop-lm-in-r

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want, but it may requires some changes to get to the full extent of what you need.

```
df <- data.frame(WD = c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
                E1 = rnorm(10,0,1),
                E2 = rnorm(10,0,1))


mod <- function(x){

  lm(WD ~ x, data = df)


}

sapply(df[setdiff(names(df),"WD")],mod)
```